# Minimum distance to paint a tennis stadium

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I am working on the fellowing exercise. We want to repaint the lines of a tennis stadium (see picture) without the net[image] and we have all the dimensions. To repaint the lines we have a robot which can move not necessarily on lines and when it is on line it repaints the line. We want to determine the path with minimum distance to the robot to repaint all the lines. The robot can finish repainting any where and it start from the above left extremity.

I tried to write the problem as a graph theory problem. Hence, I consider the complete graph with nodes the extremities of lines and the cost of an edge is the distance between the two points which form the edges. To solve the problem it is enough to find a path in the graph which goes through all the edges in the real lines of the stadium. However I do not have an idea to solve the problem. I have an idea if the path is cycle it is the famous rural postman problem. I suspect that we can construct a graph and such that the problem is equivalent to solve the rural postman problem on the late graph but I do not know how. Does anyone have an idea ?